# I'm just trying to find the difference in index between the max value of a list and other elements in the list

Tags: python

```
l = [5,8,9,4,10]   


def Max(l):
    max1 = l[0]
    for i in l:
        if i > max1:
            max1 = i
    return max1

print(Max(l))    


def distance(lista):
    l = []
    for i in lista:
        if list(Max(lista)) > lista[i]:
            ind1 = l.index(Max(lista))
            ind2 = l.index(lista)
            l.append(ind1-ind2)

    return l





distance(l)
```

cam you please tell me what's wrong with my code !
how can i make this right ?
i need to solve it using that function way i use .. thanks ^^

Comment: Can you please specify what the expected output is, and what actual output or error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
l = [5,8,9,4,10]   

def Max(l):
    max1 = l[0]
    for i in l:
        if i > max1:
            max1 = i
    return max1

print(Max(l))    


def distance(lista):
    l = []
    ind = lista.index(Max(lista))
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        l.append(ind - i)
    return l

print(distance(l))
```

Comment: that's what I'm looking for .. , thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use the key parameter of the max function to get the index of the maximum value.  Then use a list comprehension to compute the index differences:

```
lst = [5,8,9,4,10]

maxIndex = max(range(len(lst)),key=lambda i:lst[i])
result   = [i-maxIndex for i in range(len(lst))]

print(result) # [-4, -3, -2, -1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to keep my code as similar as yours, but I had to change the names.

I changed several things in your code: First I changed the maxNumber (max1) to be 0 just in case you had a list out of order. Second, the for loop in the second function wasn't correct. You had a `for i in lista:` which iterates through the loop by items so you would get first 5, then 8, then 9, when you really wanted to loop through the indices. You can do that using enumerate. Last, your second function didn't have return l.

```
myList = [5,8,9,4,10]

def find_Max_Of_List(numberList): 
    maxNumber = 0 
    for item in numberList: 
        if item > maxNumber: 
            maxNumber = item 
    return maxNumber

print(find_Max_Of_List(myList))

def distances_Of_Max_And_Indices(numberList): 
    distances = [] 
    for i, item in enumerate(numberList): 
        if find_Max_Of_List(numberList) > numberList[i]: 
            index1 = numberList.index(find_Max_Of_List(numberList)) 
            index2 = i
            distances.append(abs(index1-index2))
        else:
            distances.append(0)
    return distances

print(distances_Of_Max_And_Indices(myList))
```

There are more elegant ways of doing this. The max function `max(anyNumber)` returns the max of a list and list comprehension could do it all in one line.